# Trying to fix error in angular js app -cannot read undefined

Tags: angularjs

Im sorry for posting so much about angular tonight but im running into a lot of trouble creating my practice app and it is important I have it running and test created by tomorrow.

I had everything working a few hours ago but now only {{title}} appears on the page and I get the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'labels' of undefined. I am hoping it is just something small that I am missing but I cannot see it at all one thing I might mention is I renamed my service dataSrv from dataRepository other then that I have mostly just been writing tests (or trying too) but I dont think that has anything to do with it.

If anyone can help im getting panicky.

Thanks!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="ChartApp">
<head>
    <title>Chart.js Trial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/chartjs/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/angular-chart.js-master/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/controller/main-controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/service/data-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/directive/color-directive.js"></script>

    <link href="/Scripts/angular-chart.js-master/examples/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Scripts/angular-chart.js-master/dist/angular-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h1 add-color-header>{{title}}</h1>
        <canvas id="base" class="chart-base" chart-type="type" data="data" labels="labels" legend="true"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

data-srv.js

```
angular.module("ChartApp")
    .factory("dataSrv", function () {
        return {
            labels: ["Reading", "Coding", "Thinking About Coding", "Reddit", "StackOverflow"],
            data: [500, 300, 300, 40, 220],
            type: "PolarArea",
            title: "Angular Chart Expriment"
        };
    });
```

main-controller.js

```
var app = angular.module("ChartApp", ["chart.js"]);

 app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope",
       function ($scope, dataSrv) {
           $scope.labels = dataSrv.labels;
           $scope.data = dataSrv.data;
           $scope.type = dataSrv.type;
           $scope.title = dataSrv.title;
       }
    ]);
```

Comment: You are missing dependency injection argument for `dataSrv`. It should be `["$scope", "dataSrv",
       function ($scope, dataSrv) {`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I feel like a complete moron but you saved my butt. Thanks again